# Calculate Zero and Null values in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, validation, gridview

I have a Gridview and I want to calculate the cells which has Zero and Null values. I researched a lot and couldn't find a note.

**GridView:**

```
Size     A       B       C       D        R 
1       5.5     2.0     null    6.5       1 
2        0      3.6     3.5     3.2       2 
3       3.2     1.2     5.6     2.3       3
N/A      0       0       0       0        0
```

Now I need to validate the Null and Empty cells and I need to apply this formula to those cells which have zero and null values. In the Grid now **C1** & **A2** has zero and null values.

GridView Validation:

I can use this code to validate the empty and null values and how can I add my formula here.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow rw in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rw.Cells.Count; i++)
    {
        if (rw.Cells[i].Value == null || rw.Cells[i].Value == DBNull.Value || String.IsNullOrWhitespace(rw.Cells[i].Value.ToString())
        {
            // here is your message box...
        }
    } 
}
```

**Formula:**

```
For C1 = sum(C2/R2*R1)
For A2 = sum(A3/R3*R2)
```

But the formula shouldn't get applied for N/A row.

**GridView Binding:**

I'm not going to use any Header or ItemTemplate since the gridview is going to be in readonly mode.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" Width="985px" AllowSorting="True" GridLines="None">
    <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Times New Roman" Font-Size="Medium" Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="Blue" />
    <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" />
    <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
</asp:GridView>
```

I'm using a stored procedure to show columns in the gridview and probably I will refer the SP in the pageload event. Also pageload or in any event I have to validate these functionality. The gridview is just a report and there are no operations like add,edit,update and delete.

Also I should be able to calculate even if some other cells have Zero and Null values, the formula should be applied accordingly.

Really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: u should post some coding of it how gridview is binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try these yourself first and then post here if you are facing any problems.

Anyways, I have made some assumptions here

1. The data that is getting bound to the gridview is a datatable. If not then you can get the DataSource of the GridView to get the datatable
2. Columns in the datatable are of type string. If not then you can tweak the code as per the same

Update your datatable before binding it to the gridview.

The following code should do the trick. I have tested it a little but do thorough testing of the same.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "EmployeeDetails";
    cmd.Connection = con;

    //Create object of SqlDataAdapter here and pass object of SqlCommand
    SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    //Call Fill method of dataadapter
    ad.Fill(dt);

    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (dt.Rows[i]["Size"].ToString() == "N/A")
            continue;

        for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            object colVal = dt.Rows[i][j];
            if (colVal == DBNull.Value || Convert.ToDecimal(colVal) == 0)
            {
                decimal calVal = (Convert.ToDecimal(dt.Rows[i + 1][j]) / Convert.ToDecimal(dt.Rows[i + 1]["R"])) * Convert.ToDecimal(dt.Rows[i]["R"]);
                dt.Rows[i][j] = calVal;
            }
        }
    }

    //Replace this line of code
    //GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;

    GridView1.DataBind();

}
```

If this is not what you need then please comment.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Samar - How could I set a validation for the row N/A. Because the formula shouln't get applied for N/A and updated my post too. The N/A row will remain the same even it has null or zero values.

Comment: What is the name of the column containing "N/A" for that particular row? Or is it like you have marked the row as "N/A" where all column will contain zeros?

Comment: Size is the column name.

Comment: Thanks a lot samar. Will work on it and will let you know. Also probably I have to use this in databound event if I am correct

Comment: If you have found the answer useful then please upvote and/or mark as answer. :)

Comment: protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e){ if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow){ //will put your code here//  } }.. Can you pls let me know if this is fine.

Comment: You said you are going to use an SP on page_load event to bind data to gridview. When you are calling the SP, you must be putting the resultset in a datatable right? Put my code after you call your SP and before your set the datatable as datasource of gridview.

Comment: Samar - I have updated my code as an answer. Please review and I think I am going wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can try as inder:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender,
    DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    String value = e.Value as string;
    if ((value != null) && value.Equals(e.CellStyle.DataSourceNullValue))
    {
        e.Value = e.CellStyle.NullValue;
        e.FormattingApplied = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about trying to calculate the aggregate column in the RowDataBound event. You can determine if the cell value will be 0 or null there then make the necessary change.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e){   

if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow){ 

//check the cell values here ....

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

By far,

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "EmployeeDetails";
    cmd.Connection = con;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (dt.Rows[i]["Size"].ToString() == "N/A")
            continue;

        for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            object colVal = dt.Rows[i][j];
            if (colVal == DBNull.Value || Convert.ToDecimal(colVal) == 0)
            {
                decimal calVal = (Convert.ToDecimal(dt.Rows[i + 1][j]) / Convert.ToDecimal(dt.Rows[i + 1]["R"])) * Convert.ToDecimal(dt.Rows[i]["R"]);
                dt.Rows[i][j] = calVal;
            }
        }
    }
GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
GridView1.DataBind();

}
```

Comment: At the beginning of your code you need to create object of "SqlDataAdapter". The constructor of this class will take "SqlCommand" object as parameter. Then call "Fill" method and pass the datatable object to it. Then my code will come. Then your gridview1 binding code will come. This is a disconnected architecture. What you have used is connected architecture. My code will not work with connected architecture. I have modified my answer and given comments where there is change. Please check.